# Relation between time taken by light to pass through a glass slab and the refractive index

Tags: optics, speed-of-light, refraction

I came across the following question as an example in my book:

> A glass slab has its left half of refractive index $\mu_1$ and right half of refractive index $3\mu_1$. What is the effective refractive index of the glass slab?

The solution made use of the following equation:

> Total time = $\frac{d}{2\mu_1}+\frac{d}{2\mu_2}=\frac{d}{\mu_{eff}}$ where d is the thickness of slab

Here's where I got stuck at. Isn't the time taken by light to pass through the slab proportional to the refractive index rather than an inverse relation?
As

$$\text{velocity of light in medium}=\frac{\text{velocity of light in air}}{\mu}=\frac{c}{\mu}$$

$$\text{time}=\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{speed}}=\frac{d}{\frac{c}{\mu}}=\frac{d\mu}{c}$$

While the solution indicated the opposite relation. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Which book was it?

Comment: @ProfRob Not a mainstream book of some author... It's from a local coaching I go to

Comment: @ProfRob Is the given equation in the solution wrong? Or am I applying a different concept altogether?